# zlib support for mips32r6 and mips64r6

Tags: build, mips, zlib

I have to build or download zlib.so library or for mips32r6 and mips64r6. At first could someone tell me does zlib supports mips32r6 and mips64r6 and where can I see what mips arhitecture does zlib supports. If supports could, someone tell how to do billd zlib.so library.

Comment: Please specify the exact platform.

Comment: if this https://downloads.openwrt.org/latest/logs/ar71xx/nand/package/libs/zlib/compile.txt is example of buiding libz.so for mips32r2 does zlib suports building libz.so for mips32r6

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens? You can take one of the existing makefiles that comes with zlib and edit it to use your MIPS cross-compiler and whatever compiler flags you want. I've done that in the past for other targets, and it wasn't a lot of work.

Comment: That's good starting point.Tnx

Answer (score 0):

zlib is written to be highly portable.  Just build it.

Comment: I have just downloaded zlib source code but I don't now which makefile do I have to edit  for mips32r6 and mips64r6. Sorry I'm total beginner, some tutorial about setting flags for zlib, will help me a lot.

Comment: Those are CPU designations.  What is the operating system?  Do you know how you compile and run a simple C program?